# Sending Multipart data using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, multipart

**Interface**

```
public interface iUpload{
        @Multipart
        @POST("/uploadmultiplepropimages/")
         SamplePojoClass getUploadData(
            @Part("prop_id") RequestBody prop_id,
            @Part("type") RequestBody type,
            @Part("prop_photos") TypedFile prop_photos
        );
}
```

I'm sending like this.  I cant send request body text like this.

```
@Override

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String s = params[0];
        File photoFile = new File(s);
        System.out.println("file path:"+photoFile);
        TypedFile photoTypedFile = new TypedFile("image/png", photoFile);

        RequestBody idd = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "");
        RequestBody type = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "single");

        try {
            //uploadImageResponse = RequestResponse.getUploadData(AccountUtils.getProfileId(),photoTypedFile);
            uploadImageResponse = RequestResponse.getUploadData(idd,type,photoTypedFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }`
```

It says error:

> Cannot access ByteString class file.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you have added `okio` dependency in your gradle file. This will resolve **Cannot access ByteString class file** error.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
```

Then Edit your `iUpload` interface file like:

```
public interface iUpload{
        @Multipart
        @POST("/uploadmultiplepropimages/")
        SamplePojoClass getUploadData(
                @Part MultipartBody.Part file
                @Part MultipartBody.Part prop_id,
                @Part MultipartBody.Part type
        );
    }
```

Then write `MultipartBody.Part` like this:

```
RequestBody lRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), pFile);
     MultipartBody.Part lFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", pFile.getName(), lRequestBody);
     MultipartBody.Part id = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("prop_id", "WRITE_ID_HERE");
     MultipartBody.Part type = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("type", "WRITE TYPE HERE");
```

and finally pass these parameters to your api like this:

```
uploadImageResponse = RequestResponse.getUploadData(lFile,id,type);
```

I hope it will resolve your problem.

**Note**: Here `pFile` is instance of `File`. To get file from dicrectory you can write code like:

```
File pFile = new File("PATH_OF_FILE");
```

Comment: not working it give below error
{"headers":{"namesAndValues":["Content-Disposition","form-data; name\u003d\"prop_id\""]}}
{"headers":{"namesAndValues":["Content-Disposition","form-data; name\u003d\"type\""]}}

Comment: @LaxmanMarth please post whole error log which you get. And updated it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have done Multipart upload in okhttp. I hope this will help.
        MultipartBody.Builder multipartBuilder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
        multipartBuilder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
        multipartBuilder.addFormDataPart("prop_photos", photoFile, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, file));

            multipartBuilder
                         .addFormDataPart("type", type)
                        .addFormDataPart("prop_id", prop_id);

    RequestBody requestBody = multipartBuilder.build();
    Request request1 = new Request.Builder().url(urlString).post(requestBody).build();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following fuction for your problem

```
public static RegisterResponse Uploadimage(String id, String photo,String proof) {

        File file1 = null, file2 = null;
        try {
            if (photo.trim() != null && !photo.trim().equals("")) {
                file1 = new File(photo);
            }
            if (proof.trim() != null && !proof.trim().equals("")) {
                file2 = new File(proof);
            }

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(WEB_SERVICE + "protoupload.php?");

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

            // reqEntity.addPart("studentid", new StringBody(
            // Global.profileDetail.id));
            reqEntity.addPart("id", new StringBody(id));

            if (file1 == null) {
                reqEntity.addPart("photo", new StringBody(""));
            } else {
                FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
                reqEntity.addPart("photo", bin1);
            }
            if (file2 == null) {
                reqEntity.addPart("proof", new StringBody(""));
            } else {
                FileBody bin2 = new FileBody(file2);
                reqEntity.addPart("proof", bin2);
            }
            post.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            String inputStreamString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

            if (inputStreamString.contains("result")) {

                return new Gson().fromJson(inputStreamString,
                        RegisterResponse.class);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

        return new RegisterResponse();
    }
```