# How to POST Body and Multipart data both in one request in Retrofit 2.2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipart

I am trying to post both `@Body` and `@Part` data in same API request

like below

```
@Multipart
@POST("AccountService/MultipartProfileImageUpload")
Call<String> updateProfilePic(@Body UserIdCredentials userIdCredentials,@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

but its not working I am getting error

> @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.
>   (parameter #1)

complete error log

> 07-31 05:01:01.644 6315-6315/com.orbiosolutions.yabeee
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: com.orbiosolutions.yabeee, PID: 6315
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:1, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   (has extras) }} to activity
>   {com.orbiosolutions.yabeee/com.orbiosolutions.yabeee.Activities.HomeActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used
>   with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)
>                                                                                for method ApiInterface.updateProfilePic
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3659)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3702)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:155)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot
>   be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)
>                                                                                for method ApiInterface.updateProfilePic
>                                                                                at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:752)
>                                                                                at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:743)
>                                                                                at
>   retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:761)
>                                                                                at
>   retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:701)
>                                                                                at
>   retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(ServiceMethod.java:336)
>                                                                                at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:204)
>                                                                                at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
>                                                                                at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
>                                                                                at $Proxy0.updateProfilePic(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at
>   com.orbiosolutions.yabeee.Fragments.ProfileFragment.uploadProfilImg(ProfileFragment.java:191)
>                                                                                at
>   com.orbiosolutions.yabeee.Fragments.ProfileFragment.onCropImg(ProfileFragment.java:527)
>                                                                                at
>   com.orbiosolutions.yabeee.Fragments.ProfileFragment.onActivityResult(ProfileFragment.java:506)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6222)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3655)
>                                                                                 ... 10 more

Please some one help me to fix this

Comment: i answered this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413327/how-to-send-image-data-along-with-two-more-fields-of-string-data-to-server-using/45413567#45413567

Comment: @AnandSingh thank u its working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the reference of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413327/how-to-send-image-data-along-with-two-more-fields-of-string-data-to-server-using/45413567#45413567) answer I made changes like this and its working fine.

**Request**

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestBody);
        MultipartBody.Part id = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("userId", userId);
        //Creating a rest adapter
        ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<ProfilePicUpdateResponse> call = apiService.updateProfilePic(id,fileToUpload);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ProfilePicUpdateResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProfilePicUpdateResponse> call, Response<ProfilePicUpdateResponse> response) {

                loading.dismiss();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("Success", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                }
                else
                {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    csActivity.showMsg(getResources().getString(R.string.something_error));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProfilePicUpdateResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                loading.dismiss();
                Log.d("=========>>", t.getMessage().toString());
                Log.d("============>>>", "Failure");
            }
        });
```

**InterfaceClass**

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("AccountService/MultipartProfileImageUpload")
    Call<ProfilePicUpdateResponse> updateProfilePic(@Part MultipartBody.Part userId, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Comment: Tx, that really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Post this

```
@Multipart
@POST("AccountService/MultipartProfileImageUpload")Call<String> 
updateProfilePic(@Body UserIdCredentials 
userIdCredentials,@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

To this

```
@Multipart
@POST("AccountService/MultipartProfileImageUpload")Call<String> 
updateProfilePic(@part("params") UserIdCredentials 
userIdCredentials,@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

and get request body as **params** at server end

Comment: i get this error with this solution : the request entity's media type 'multipart\ /form-data' is not supported for this resource

Answer (score -1):

Use below code:

Interface:

```
 @Multipart
@POST("/ws_services.php?action=imageupload")
public void imageupload(@Part("image") TypedFile file, Callback<Example> callback);
```

Activity.java

```
                 TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("image/*", new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));

                    ApiHandler.getApiService().imageupload(typedFile, new Callback<Example>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Example example, Response response) {
                            try {
                                String status = example.getSuccess();
                                if (status.equals("1"))
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),example.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),example.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                Log.e("status", "0");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            Log.e("retrofit error log", error.toString());
                        }
                    });
```